# Getting exact date and time by new row in Google Sheets via Zapier

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, timestamp, zapier

I have a simple but stubborn problem. I have data from our ESP which I send via Zapier into a Google Sheet. Unfortunately, I can not send the SignUp date from the ESP via Zapier, so I am looking for a solution to create the date by a new entry within the Google Sheet.

I've tried =TODAY() and =NOW() inside the row in Zapier, so the function will be put in every single time from Zapier. The problem is, that both of these functions give me every time the time of *just right now*, so if I have a week-old entry, it still shows me that it is from today.

Next, I've tried to use an array function.

=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(ISBLANK($B4376:$B)=TRUE, "", NOW()))

But I have the same exact problem, the momentary date of the input is not saved but always just right now overwritten.

Does anybody have any idea how I could create a date & time by entry?

Thankful for any ideas!

Comment: you need a timestamp script

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Zapier supports date/time commands in the action fields.  All you need to do is add one of these commands when you're setting up the action.

You can use one of the following entries:

- {{zap_meta_human_now}}
- {{zap_meta_utc_iso}}
- {{zap_meta_timestamp}}

There are also entries for all the US timezones

- EST: {{zap_meta_est_iso}} ISO-8601 formatted date and time in Eastern Standard Time
- EDT: {{zap_meta_edt_iso}} ISO-8601 formatted date and time in Eastern Daylight Time
- CST: {{zap_meta_cst_iso}} ISO-8601 formatted date and time in Central Standard Time
- CDT: {{zap_meta_cdt_iso}} ISO-8601 formatted date and time in Central Daylight Time
- MST: {{zap_meta_mst_iso}} ISO-8601 formatted date and time in Mountain Standard Time
- MDT: {{zap_meta_mdt_iso}} ISO-8601 formatted date and time in Mountain Daylight Time
- PST: {{zap_meta_pst_iso}} ISO-8601 formatted date and time in Pacific Standard Time
  PDT: {{zap_meta_pdt_iso}} ISO-8601 formatted date and time in Pacific Daylight Time

For more info see https://zapier.com/help/create/customize/insert-the-time-your-zap-runs-into-a-field

#### Source data (without date/time)

[image: Source worksheet]

#### Destination data (with date/time added by Zap)

[image: Destination worksheet]

#### Example set-up to add date/time

[image: Iso date command]

[image: Adding iso date to field]

Comment: Thank you! That was the solution. Zapier doesn't have all timezones, but at least we get the correct days now!

Answer (score 0):

I've found a script but it only works on manual edit. By input from Zapier the script does not react. I've tried it with doGet instead of onEdit, but I get no results..

```html
var SHEET_NAME = 'Boxes Dog Live Dashboard';
var DATETIME_HEADER = 'date';

function getDatetimeCol(){
  var headers = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(SHEET_NAME).getDataRange().getValues().shift();
  var colindex = headers.indexOf(DATETIME_HEADER);
  return colindex+1;
}

function doGet(e) {  
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var cell = ss.getActiveCell();
  var datecell = ss.getRange(cell.getRowIndex(), getDatetimeCol());
  if (ss.getName() == SHEET_NAME && cell.getColumn() == 2 && !cell.isBlank() && datecell.isBlank()) {      
    datecell.setValue(new Date()).setNumberFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm");
  }
};
```